# how to disable a link_to with condition, using slim in ruby ​on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I'm new to slim and ruby ​​on rails and trying to figure out how to disable a link_to if the
condition isn't required.

```
f.actions do
      = f.submit 'save data'
      = link_to 'send data'
```

Here f, is a form that the user fills, and when the form condition is not met, that means submit asks user to fill some required field, I want link_to "send data" to be disabled
How can I do that guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails include multiple `link_to` helpers to display a link if a specific condition is met.

`link_to_if`

https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if

`link_to_unless`

https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_unless

Comment: Ya, thank. I think it is the better solution.